# Jquery validate is not triggering for day field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script and its triggering just when i click first time on textbox:

```
var day = parseInt($("#day_birthdate").val(), 10);
    jQuery('input#day_birthdate').bind('input propertychange', function () {
        if (day >= 1 || day <=31) {
            jQuery(this).css({ 'background': 'green' });


        } else {
            jQuery(this).css({ 'background': 'red' });

        }
    });
```

I have this textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Day, new { id = "day_birthdate", @class = "form-control", mask = "99", @placeholder = "dd" })
```

When i click on textbox its triggering but for first time value is NaN and its red but when i put some number its nots triggering anymore...so i need to change this somehow so when user type numbers between 1 and 31 to get green textbox.Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `input change paste` event?

Comment: When i use change...day is always NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('input#day_birthdate').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    var day = parseInt($("#day_birthdate").val(), 10); //Getting the value after change

    if (day >= 1 && day <= 31) { // Changed || to && because both must be true
        jQuery(this).css({
            'background': 'green'
        });        
    } else {
        jQuery(this).css({
            'background': 'red'
        });    
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/k5ecocp4/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move `day` assignment to event body, because this code:

```
var day = parseInt($("#day_birthdate").val(), 10);
jQuery('input#day_birthdate').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    if (day >= 1 || day <=31) {
```

is getting value on page load, and only comparing values when you type to field. Move `var day = ...` to body of event:

```
jQuery('#day_birthdate').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    var day = parseInt($("#day_birthdate").val(), 10);

    if (day >= 1 || day <=31) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get input value in event.

```
var day = ''; 
jQuery('input#day_birthdate').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    day = parseInt($("#day_birthdate").val(), 10);
    if (day >= 1 || day <=31) {
        jQuery(this).css({ 'background': 'green' });
    } else {
        jQuery(this).css({ 'background': 'red' });

    }
});
```